# Showing in html, the value calculated in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, label, output, frontend

I am just getting started with JavaScript so it is a fairly simple question..

I have a value "x" which was calculated/derived in a JavaScript function "y".

I wish to display this value in HTML. I am using Internet Explorer (yeah..) and the "" tag is not valid here...

Since it is a single vale I won't be using a dropdown box. The other alternative being "". Can I show this value in a label? If so how, if not what do I do?

Comment: Where is your code ? What is __`""`__ tag ?

Comment: You should post the code/program.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can use any element you like. The usual DOM methods (`document.createTextNode`, `someElement.appendChild`, etc) will work.

A `<label>` almost certainly wouldn't be suitable though. It is designed to tell the user what to enter into an input or other form control.

Pick the element which has the semantics that best match that data you are outputting. (Keeping in mind that if nothing has suitable semantics then `<div>` and `<span>` don't have any so are the safe fallback).

Answer (score 0):

Say you have value "X",

With the following Markup:

```
<label id="lblMyValue">
</label>
```

Your code, should look for the DomElement with that ID:

```
document.getElementById("lblMyValue").innerHTML= X;
```

I was also a beginner (and am still learning a lot), and I must give you the following advice: Start using JQuery. Even if it is not always wanted, coding with it when you can will really teach you the "ins and outs" as it were, of JavaScript.

Have Fun Learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the calculated result in a variety of places, depending on what makes the most sense. If you want to show it in an element that contains HTML, you would use the `innerHTML` property. If you want to show it in some input element, you could use `value` instead.

```js
var result = 2 + 2;

document.getElementById('infoSpan').innerHTML = result;
document.getElementById('infoTextInput').value = result;
```

```html
<div>Result: <span id="infoSpan"></span></div>

<div>Result: <input id="infoTextInput" type="text" /></div>
```